Cannot save form data to the Atlas database with admin panel
I am trying to follow this tutorial about a food ordering website as a beginner and while making the admin panel, I am unable to add the food item I want to submit via the form to the mongoose atlas database that I have setup for it.
Here is the component for adding the food item;
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./Add.css";
import { assets } from "../../assets/assets";
import axios from "axios"
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

const Add = () => {

  const url = "http://localhost:5173";
  const [image, setImage] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    name:"",
    description:"",
    price:"",
    category:"Salad"
  })

  const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    setData(data =>({...data, [name]:value}))
  }
  
  const onSubmitHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", data.name)
    formData.append("description", data.description)
    formData.append("price", Number(data.price))
    formData.append("category", data.category)
    formData.append("image", image)
    const response = await axios.post(`${url}/api/food/add`, formData);
    
    if (response.data.success) {
      setData({
        name:"",
        description:"",
        price:"",
        category:"Salad"
      })
      setImage(false)
      toast.success(response.data.message)
    }
    else {
      toast.error(response.data.message)
    }
  } 

  return (
    <div className="add">
      <form className="flex-col" onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
        <div className="add-img-upload flex-col">
          <p>Upload Image</p>
          <label htmlFor="image">
            <img src={image?URL.createObjectURL(image):assets.upload_area} alt="" />
          </label>
          <input onClick={(e)=>setImage(e.target.files[0])} type="file" id="image" hidden required />
        </div>
        <div className="add-product-name flex-col">
          <p>Product name</p>
          <input onChange={onChangeHandler} value={data.name} type="text" name="name" placeholder="Type here" />
        </div>
        <div className="add-product-description flex-col">
          <p>Product description</p>
          <textarea onChange={onChangeHandler} value={data.description}
            name="description"
            rows="6"
            placeholder="Write content here"
            required
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div className="add-category-price">
          <div className="add-category flex-col">
            <p>Product category</p>
            <select onChange={onChangeHandler} name="category">
              <option value="Salad">Salad</option>
              <option value="Rolls">Rolls</option>
              <option value="Deserts">Deserts</option>
              <option value="Sandwich">Sandwich</option>
              <option value="Cake">Cake</option>
              <option value="Pure Veg">Pure Veg</option>
              <option value="Pasta">Pasta</option>
              <option value="Noodles">Noodles</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className="add-price flex-col">
            <p>Product price</p>
            <input onChange={onChangeHandler} value={data.price} type="Number" name="price" placeholder="$20" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="add-btn">ADD</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Add;


Here is the github repository for what I have done so far, if anyone wants to have a look at the backend.
I think there might be a problem with connecting the admin to the backend or just the admin because when I tried to add the food item to the database using Thunder Client, it worked. I also am clueless about actually where the fault might lie, if it has anything to do with the backend.
Edit: upon performing inspect on the Add.jsx component, the following errors are shown;
No routes matched location "/" 
warning @ react-router-dom

When I try to fill the form the errors are;
POST http://localhost:3000/api/food/add net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

and
AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
: 
"ERR_NETWORK"


You are using FormData() so it will be sent to your backend as multipart/form-data. However, express cannot parse multipart/form-datawithout something like multer. Your express.json() middleware only parses JSON encoded data. Also, you have your username and password exposed on GitHub in your mongoose connection string. I would advise you change it on Atlas immediately.

@jQueeny Thank you, I overlooked that. I have changed the credentials now, but that was a kind of throwaway Atlas account I made to learn stuff. Not connected to anything else but thank you anyways! Also, I am using multer in the foodRoute component in the backend, will that not help? It is supposed to upload the input data to the uploads folder.

Sorry yes I can see multer there. I was looking in your controller. Does the image upload successfully but the document fail to save to Atlas? Is that the problem? If so the await food.save(); would thrown an error which will be caught and output to console in your console.log(error).

Yes, that's what is happening! But I am not getting any errors on that page.

Are you getting the {success: true, message:"Food Added"} response back then if it's not throwing an error?

Not at all, it's like the add button is doing nothing.

I fixed it! Turns out, I was using onClick for the image upload section on line 56 and onChange for everything else.
The image was still uploading, but the formData was not getting saved to the Atlas database. I changed it to onChange instead, and it works now. The resulting code snippet being:
<input onChange={(e)=>setImage(e.target.files[0])} type="file" id="image" hidden />

